# WebBrowser control > Replace InnerText of HtmlElement > How to refresh?

Tags: c#, events, replace, webbrowser-control, innertext

I'm replacing the InnerText of some HtmlElements.
This works fine on the `DocumentCompleted` event.

If the user hits F5, `DocumentCompleted` isn't fired again, same with `Navigated`.
I hooked into `PreviewKeyDown` and do the replacements on F5, but the WebBrowser control shows the original text then.
I tried `Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.???)` method here with no success.

a) Is there any other event that is fired on F5?
b) How to refresh the page after catching F5?
c) How to force the WebBrowser control to display applied changes?